# How to play .amr file on a website?

Tags: html, web, amr

i have tried below code but not working ? does anyone play amr files in website

```html
<audio id="audio" src="upload/hello2.amr"
       preload="auto" controls muted loop autoplay>
</audio>
```

any plugin or player which can play amr file in web

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AMR file is not one of the supported audio files that html5 audio tag supports. Please see the list below for supported audio formats:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio#Supported_audio_coding_formats

I would recommend you convert your amr file to mp3 or ogg and then upload it and play it on your server.

---

original answer:

Your code specifies an **mp3** file. Are you sure you put in the amr file?

Comment: html5 is not supported but any other solution for amr

Comment: nope, not really... you can read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322000/is-there-a-browser-embedded-player-that-can-play-3gp-amr-mid-mp3-wav