# How to play an audio amr file in computer using HTML code? I tried many time

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

this side Priti and my question is- How to play an audio/amr file in computer using HTML code?

Comment: Show your code that you have tried.

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: Convert it, its not supported in html audio tags.

Comment: <audio controls>
<source src = "sample.amr" type = "audio/amr" >
</audio>

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code

```
<audio controls>
<source src="<?php echo $file;?>" type="audio/ogg">
Your browser does not support the audio element
</audio>
```

Comment: not working, same problem in this code i already use that

Comment: Please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915454/how-to-play-amr-file-on-a-website)